# htaccess Internal server error, authentication loop

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I am attempting to set up  htaccess to restrict access to a particular folder.  I currently have as follows:

Htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted area"
AuthUserFile /home3/user/public_html/.htpasswd
require valid-user

ErrorDocument 404 "Error"
ErrorDocument 401 "Error"
ErrorDocument 403 "Error"
```

htpasswd:

```
Guest:GuestPassword
```

Using this method I will either have a 500 server error returned, OR it will loop and continuously prompt me for authentication.

Any help is appreciated!

ALSO: I used **showphp()** to get the Document root.  So AuthUserFile path should be correct.

Thanks!

Comment: That seems... a weird `.htpasswd` to me.. Usually an encrypted password is added by running `htpasswd /path/to/.htpasswd username`, have you tried that?

Comment: Ive seen reference to that but I have not done that yet.  How would you go about doing that?

Comment: You mean by writing to the file rather then editing by hand correct?

Comment: You also shouldn't have you .htapassword file in your web directory.

Comment: Oops, yes I meant for it to be at the root, not the root public folder.

Comment: Would that have made a difference?  I can try that right away

Comment: @user2138152: you'd do that by running that exact code on the command line, or if you don't have access to that for some reason [online solutions are available](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

Answer (score 6):

The infinite loop asking for your password is what you want to see. That means you typed in your password wrong.  The Internal Server 500 Error means you have another issue in your code.  The reason your username and password aren't working is because your server expects the password to be hashed.

Change your .htpasswd file to:

```
Guest:$apr1$u5E5vgOR$6rPNEYkeaF5IVE4c3FyKM0
```

(The password is GuestPassword)